# SSRS Gauge Chart

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

i just want to know is it possible to have the Legend in SSRS Guage Chart like above

[image]

I am able to get the guage but this legend is possible?

if yes how i will get.

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in way I can think of in SSRS to do this.

Can't you put your picture next to your gauge?

Grab a screenshot of your gauge and use a dropper to get the gray color and border color and apply them to your legends to make it match.